# Nestjs issue regarding modules

Tags: typescript, nestjs

imagine we have RequestResponseInterceptor and typeorm.forFeature([RequestResponseEntity]) in RequestResponseModule and i use this SomeEntityRepository in interceptor. then i want to use this interceptor in SomeModule's controller how should i do it?

I have it like this:

```
export class RequestResponseModule {
  static registerAsync(): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: RequestResponseModule,
      imports: [HttpModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([RequestResponseEntity])],
      providers: [NasPhHttpService, RequestResponseInterceptor, RequestResponseScheduler],
      exports: [NasPhHttpService, RequestResponseInterceptor],
    };
  }
}
```

And SomeModule looks like this:

```
@Module({
imports: [HttpModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ExtPaymentKafkaEventDto]), RequestResponseModule.registerAsync()], providers: [SomeService, ExtPaymentRepository, ConfigService, SomeAuth], controllers: [SomeController], exports: [SomeService], }) export class SomeModule {}
```

and in controller i use it like this:

```
@UseInterceptors(RequestResponseInterceptor)
```

but i have an error that says:

```
[Nest] 99697  - 08/17/2023, 6:21:50 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RequestResponseInterceptor (?). Please make sure that the argument RequestResponseEntityRepository at index [0] is available in the SomeModule context.
```

I tried not to use RequestResponseInterceptor like interceptor and just injected it in constuctor and it does not give me an error. So maybe I should inject it differently?

I tried not to use RequestResponseInterceptor like interceptor and just injected it in constuctor and it does not give me an error. So maybe I should inject it differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `TypeOrmModule` to the `exports` of the `RequestResponseModule` so that the `RequestResponseRepository` gets exported, then you can import the `RequestResponseModule` in whatever module has a controller that you are using the `RequestResponseInterceptor` and it will work as intended.

Enhancers aren't a perfect 1:1 with providers, and they don't share instance scope the same way that providers do via modules, so you have to do things a little differently